# Django: Disable cache_page in middleware or conditionally on a request parameter

Tags: python, django, caching, django-middleware

Suppose I have a middleware that detects whether a particular request comes from a particular machine:

```
class HomeIpMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.home_ip = False
        ip = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")
        if ip == "123.456.789.101":
            request.home_ip = True
        return
```

Suppose I have a view that is used for public consumption but that generates an overlay on my site with extra admin information when `home_ip=True`:

```
@cache_page(60 x 60)
def home(request):
    output = {}
    output['public_things'] = PUBLIC_DATA
    if request.home_ip:
        output['secret_things'] = SECRET_DATA
    return render_to_response('home.html', 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'output': output})
```

As this view is cached, if I access it from `home_ip` the page is cached, with my secret information.

I accept that this is hacky, but is there a way to either:

1. Disable site-wide in some middleware the cache for a `home_ip=True` request so that it doesn't generate a page cache; or
2. Make the `cache_page` decorator conditional on `not request.home_ip`?

Comment: I suppose you could drop all of that, and use fragment caching:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching

Comment: I could - but I'm not interested in caching the admin pages at all as they need to be 100% live - and `cache_page` works perfectly for public users as-is...

Comment: As I said, conditional caching will allow you to cache the page as is, yet you can control admin related parts not to be cached...The other way you could go, is cache within the view and drop template caching, if the user matches the criteria load a fresh copy, if not fetch the cached view.

Comment: I believe you can add a new HTTP header with something like `X-Home-IP` and use the `@vary_on_headers` decorator. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers This is extremely hacky.